# Return same underlying Python boost::python::object from function returning shared_ptr

Tags: boost-python

In my application I am wrapping C++ objects through boost::shared_ptr through boost::python.

The issue I have is that any time I return a reference in C++, boost allocates a new object to point at the reference instead of reusing an existing Python object. Among other things, this breaks equality tests and custom properties that may have been set in Python.

Is there a clean, simple way to get boost::python to automatically reuse the existing boost::python::object (or at least PyObject) each time I give it a shared_ptr that points at the same underlying object?

Example code:

C++:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

class Apple {};

boost::shared_ptr<Apple> theMoldyApple(new Apple());

boost::shared_ptr<Apple> getMoldyApple() {
    //pretend we do some logic here that won't always return theMoldyApple 
    //exactly
    return theMoldyApple;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(bobtest) {
    class_<Apple, boost::shared_ptr<Apple>>("Apple", init<>());

    def("getMoldyApple", getMoldyApple);
}
```

Python:

```
from bobtest import *

# Set a custom property on the Python object:
ma = getMoldyApple()
ma.customProp = 11

# This works fine because ma is the same PyObject is was above:
print "ma.customProp:", ma.customProp

# This doesn't work because boost::python wraps a copy of the shared_ptr
# (that points to theMoldyApple) with a new PyObject each time I call
# getMoldyApple()
print "getMoldyApple().customProp:", getMoldyApple().customProp
```

Result:

```
ma.customProp: 11
getMoldyApple().customProp:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Apple' object has no attribute 'customProp'
```

Desired result:

```
ma.customProp: 11
getMoldyApple().customProp: 11
```

Comment: Did you ever find an elegant solution to this problem? I've run into the same thing while trying to add some Python attributes to objects returned by Boost.Python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it as follows:

```
class_<Apple>("Apple", no_init)
    .def("__init__", make_constructor(getMoldyApple))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a wrapper class that holds the Python object and inform Boost using `has_back_reference`.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/has_back_reference.html

Answer (score -1):

I posted at code review a generic solution with a custom converter and a map as cache:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/130044/same-pyobject-for-a-shared-ptr-c-object